# Rendering and Saving Django forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to create a form which had multiple check boxes. However,form loads fine but the data is not saved.I am able to save data by entering data in admin but not in form. If i save the form in views without `is_valid()` then form saves with the default values and not those i entered in the form.Also checkbox values raise an error:'antibiotics' is not a valid value for a primary key,say, if i select antibiotics. I'm new to django so please excuse if i'm doing basics wrong.

models.py:

```
class Taken24h(models.Model):
    CHOICES_EATEN = (
        ('antibiotics', 'Antibiotics'),
        ('steroids', 'Steroids'),
        ...
    )
    val = models.CharField(max_length=40,choices=CHOICES_EATEN,blank=True,null=True)


    class BloodDonation(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=False,null=True)
        date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True,blank=False)
        nationality = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False,null=True)
        ... 
        taken_following_in_last_24_hrs = models.ManyToManyField(Taken24h,blank=True)
```

forms.py:

```
    class BloodDonationForm(forms.ModelForm):   
        name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput,required=True)
        date_of_birth = forms.CharField(widget=forms.DateInput,required=True)
        nationality = forms.CharField()
    ...


        taken_following_in_last_24_hrs = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Taken24h.objects.all(),
widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,required=False)
    )

        class Meta:
            model = BloodDonation
            fields = '__all__'
        def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
            super(BloodDonationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['taken_following_in_last_24_hrs'].choices = Taken24h.CHOICES_EATEN
```

views.py:

```
def forms(request):
    form = BloodDonationForm(request.POST or None)      
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save(commit=True)          
    else:
        print("Invalid")    
    data = {
    'form':form,
    }
    return render(request,"forms.html",data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this answer will help, but from codes you wrote, you forgot to type request.method before processing the form in views.py file

```
def forms(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BloodDonationForm(request.POST or None)      
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)          
        else:
            print("Invalid")
    else:
        form = BloodDonationForm()

    data = {
        'form':form,
    }

    return render(request,"forms.html", data)
```